# My PS3 controller won't reconnect after plugging the cable back in

Tags: ps3, controllers

When my PS3 controller is connected with the cable it remains connected, but when I remove the cable it disconnects and won't connect again.
Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solving if you are connecting the ps3 controller to a ps3 console.

This could mean two possible problems:

One is that your controller has a malfunction with its Bluetooth chip (which is also the microprocessor). Another is your console has a malfunction with its Bluetooth chip.

To see which one is try to connect a different controller to the console, if it works then is the first problem if not its the second, its usually the second problem.

The problem solving if you are connecting the ps3 controller to a pc are the same, except that your motherboard may not be able to make a Bluetooth connection. Check if it can.

Solution to this problem

Easiest solution is to buy a new ps3 console or controller depending on the problem.

Hard solution is to fix it by your own hand and hard work which means opening the ps3 console or controller and change the necessary components to fix the issue.

I have a couple of video if you want to see how to to the Hard solution.

- [Video of how to disassemble a ps3](https://youtu.be/bOJnPxIUhI4)
- [Video of the possible Bluetooth chip solution](https://youtu.be/dS1Kwg8QRqk) (you don't have to do with cables but if you are capable do it)
- [Video of how to disassemble the ps3 controller](https://youtu.be/ximxvLSxxYE)
- [Link for the ps3 controller specifics and schematics](https://omegatechofficial.weebly.com/uploads/2/8/2/8/28284697/reverse_engineering_document.pdf)